# Finding the distance between the two closest points in a 2-D plane

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, computational-geometry, clustering

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import math
def dist(a,b):
    return math.hypot((b[0]-a[0]),(b[1]-a[1]))

def minimum_distance(x, y):
    points = list(zip(x,y))
    points_y = sorted(points, key= lambda z:z[1])
    points.sort(key=lambda g:g[0])
    return min_dist(points,points_y)

def min_dist(points,points_y):
    if len(points)==2: return dist(points[0],points[1])
    elif len(points)==3: return min(dist(points[0],points[1]),dist(points[0],points[2]),dist(points[1],points[2]))
    ave = (len(points)+1)//2
    yleft = [t for t in points_y if t[0]<=points[ave-1][0]]
    yright = [q for q in points_y if q[0]>=points[ave][0]]
    d1 = min_dist(points[0:ave],yleft)
    d2 = min_dist(points[ave:len(points)],yright)
    d = min(d1,d2)
    arr_split = [point for point in points_y if abs(point[0]- points[ave][0]) <= d]
    d_=2*(10**18)
    for i in range(len(arr_split)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,min(len(arr_split),i+7)):
            temp = dist(arr_split[i],arr_split[j])
            if temp<d_:d_=temp
    return min(d,d_)
```

Example input:([2,5,1],[3,6,2]) and output is \$ \sqrt 2 \$ since (2,3) and (1,2) are the closest points. The input arrays to minimum_distance are the x and y values of each point respectively and the inputs to min_dist are the points sorted based on their x values and y values respectively.

I have implemented pre-sort and have used computational geometric theory (comparison between 7 points only in the strip) to make the time complexity \$ O(n \log n) \$ and my code works swiftly and correctly for most test cases. However, for some hidden test cases generated by Coursera, my code is taking more than 20 seconds. Any optimisations/ corrections?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output -- from my understanding of the problem you could easily come up with an O(n) solution.

Comment: Yes example input:([2,5,1],[3,6,2]) and output is sqrt(2) since (2,3) and (1,2) are the closest points. The input arrays are the x and y values of each point respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Coding style

Your code is difficult to read because it is written very condensed.

There is a well-established coding style for Python, the 
[PEP8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
and conformance to that style can be checked online at
[PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com).

In your case it reports “missing space around operator” in almost every
code line, also “line too long” and “multiple statements on one line”
violations. As an example,

```
elif len(points)==3: return min(dist(points[0],points[1]),dist(points[0],points[2]),dist(points[1],points[2]))
```

is better written as

```
elif len(points) == 3:
    return min(dist(points[0], points[1]),
               dist(points[0], points[2]),
               dist(points[1], points[2]))
```

#### Variable naming

Another aspect which makes the code difficult to understand is the
naming of variables. Here are some examples:

```
points_y = sorted(points, key= lambda z:z[1])
points.sort(key=lambda g:g[0])
```

The parameter names `z` and `g` seem to be arbitrary. Why are they different
at all if they both refer to a point? Similarly at

```
yleft = [t for t in points_y if t[0]<=points[ave-1][0]]
yright = [q for q in points_y if q[0]>=points[ave][0]]
```

Why `t` and `q`? I'd suggest `point` or `p` in all those places.

```
def min_dist(points,points_y):
```

Both parameters contain all points, just sorted differently (by x and y,
respectively). Why the asymmetry in the parameter names? I'd suggest

```
def min_dist(points_x, points_y):
```

here, plus a doc comment *explaining* the meaning of the parameters.

```
ave = (len(points)+1)//2
```

makes one think of “average” but is just half of the list length.

#### Some simplifications

```
import sys
```

is not needed. The inner parentheses in

```
return math.hypot((b[0]-a[0]),(b[1]-a[1]))
```

are not needed. The `elif` in

```
elif len(points)==3:
```

can be replaced by an `if`. The slicing in

```
d1 = min_dist(points[0:ave],yleft)
d2 = min_dist(points[ave:len(points)],yright)
```

can be simplified to

```
d1 = min_dist(points[:ave], yleft)
d2 = min_dist(points[ave:], yright)
```

#### Validate the input

The program aborts with `RecursionError` or `IndexError` if zero or
one point are passed to the function. You should validate the input
and throw an appropriate exception in those cases.

#### A possible problem

If `points[ave-1][0] == points[ave][0]` (which means that more than one point
lies on the dividing vertical line) then elements from the `point_y`
list are assigned to both `yleft` and `yright`:

```
yleft = [t for t in points_y if t[0]<=points[ave-1][0]]
yright = [q for q in points_y if q[0]>=points[ave][0]]
```

which means that in the recursive calls

```
d1 = min_dist(points[0:ave],yleft)
d2 = min_dist(points[ave:len(points)],yright)
```

the second list is not necessarily a rearrangement of the first list anymore.

I haven't found an example where this leads to a wrong result, but it could
be an performance problem because “too large” lists are passed down the 
recursion. As an extremal case, if all points have the same x-coordinate
then `yleft` and `yright` will always be the complete initial `points_y`
list.

#### Performance improvements

`points[ave][0]]` is accessed multiple times, it might be advantageous to
assign that value to a variable once.

The initial value

```
d_=2*(10**18)
```

is a bit arbitrary, but actually not needed: In the following loop we are
only interested in points having a distance less than the previously 
computed minimum distance in the left and right half:

```
d = min(d1, d2)
# ...
for i in range(len(arr_split) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, min(len(arr_split), i + 7)):
        temp = dist(arr_split[i], arr_split[j])
        if temp < d:
            d = temp
return d
```

And while it is true that pairs of points having a distance less than `d`
are at most seven (or six?) indices apart, it seems to be more efficient
to leave the inner loop if the y-coordinates differ by `d` or more:

```
for i in range(len(arr_split) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(arr_split)):
        if arr_split[j][1] - arr_split[i][1] >= d:
            break
        temp = dist(arr_split[i], arr_split[j])
        if temp < d:
            d = temp
return d
```

#### Further suggestions

Instead of storing the point coordinates a a tuple you could define a 
custom class

```
class Point:
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

so that you can access the x- and y-coordinates of a point with `p.x`
and `p.y` instead of subscripting.